# combine select queries with count(*), group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 select queries:

Query 1:

```
select MMBID, MMBStartDate, MMBEnddate from MMBT1, MMBT2
where MMBT1.Profile_ID = MMBT2.Profile_ID
```

Query 2:

```
(SELECT Profile_ID, COUNT(vp.Viewed_ProfileId) AS viewed FROM dbo.Viewed_Profiles vp
  GROUP BY vp.Profile_Id),
```

Query 3:

```
SELECT Profile_ID, COUNT(fp.Favorite_ProfileId) AS favorites FROM dbo.Favorite_Profiles fp
  GROUP BY fp.Profile_Id
```

Now how I combine all these 3 select sts and get the follwing columns as output

- from Query1: `MMBID, MMBStartDate, MMBEnddate`
- from query2: `COUNT(vp.Viewed_ProfileId) AS viewed`
- from Query3: `COUNT(fp.Favorite_ProfileId) AS favorites`

Thanks for ur help
Sun

```
  (SELECT Profile_ID, COUNT(vp.Viewed_ProfileId) AS viewed FROM dbo.Viewed_Profiles vp
  GROUP BY vp.Profile_Id),
  (SELECT Profile_ID, COUNT(fp.Favorite_ProfileId) AS favorites FROM dbo.Favorite_Profiles fp
  GROUP BY fp.Profile_Id
   )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with one as 
(select MMBID, MMBStartDate, MMBEnddate, MMBT1.Profile_ID 
from MMBT1, MMBT2 where MMBT1.Profile_ID = MMBT2.Profile_ID),
two as
(SELECT Profile_ID, COUNT(vp.Viewed_ProfileId) AS viewed 
FROM dbo.Viewed_Profiles vp  GROUP BY vp.Profile_Id),
three as
(SELECT Profile_ID, COUNT(fp.Favorite_ProfileId) AS favorites 
FROM dbo.Favorite_Profiles fp  GROUP BY fp.Profile_Id)

select one.MMBID, one.MMBStartDate, one.MMBEndDate, two.viewed, three.favorites
from one inner join two on one.Profile_ID = two.Profile_ID
inner join  three on two.Profile_ID=three.profile_ID
```

Comment: spot on.. Thanks guys for ur help. Now I learnt a new clause "With"

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  MMBID,
  MMBStartDate,
  MMBEnddate,
  vp.viewed,
  fp.favorites
FROM MMBT1
  INNER JOIN MMBT2 ON MMBT1.Profile_ID = MMBT2.Profile_ID

  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      Profile_ID,
      COUNT(Viewed_ProfileId) AS viewed
    FROM dbo.Viewed_Profiles
    GROUP BY Profile_ID
  ) vp ON MMBT1.Profile_ID = vp.Profile_ID

  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      Profile_ID,
      COUNT(Favorite_ProfileId) AS favorites
    FROM dbo.Favorite_Profiles
    GROUP BY Profile_ID
  ) fp ON MMBT1.Profile_ID = fp.Profile_ID
```

If some `MMBT1.Profile_ID` values do not have matches in either `vp` or `fp` subselects, the corresponding rows will not be included in the result set. If that is not desirable and you want all the rows from the join of `MMBT1` & `MMBT2` preserved, use LEFT JOINs:

```
SELECT
  MMBID,
  MMBStartDate,
  MMBEnddate,
  COALESCE(vp.viewed, 0) AS viewed,
  COALESCE(fp.favorites, 0) AS favorites
FROM MMBT1
  INNER JOIN MMBT2 ON MMBT1.Profile_ID = MMBT2.Profile_ID

  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      Profile_ID,
      COUNT(Viewed_ProfileId) AS viewed
    FROM dbo.Viewed_Profiles
    GROUP BY Profile_ID
  ) vp ON MMBT1.Profile_ID = vp.Profile_ID

  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      Profile_ID,
      COUNT(Favorite_ProfileId) AS favorites
    FROM dbo.Favorite_Profiles
    GROUP BY Profile_ID
  ) fp ON MMBT1.Profile_ID = fp.Profile_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, if I understand your question properly:

```
select t1.Profile_ID, t1.MMBID, t1.MMBStartDate, t1.MMBEndDate,
t2.viewed as ProfileViews, t3.viewed as FavoriteViews
FROM
(
Select MMBT1.Profile_ID, MMBID, MMBStartDate, MMBEndDate from MMBT1, MMBT2 where MMBT1.Profile_ID = MMBT2.Profile_ID
)t1
inner join
(
SELECT Profile_ID, COUNT(vp.Viewed_ProfileId) AS viewed FROM dbo.Viewed_Profiles vp GROUP BY vp.Profile_Id
)t2 on t1.Profile_ID = t2.Profile_ID
inner join
(
SELECT Profile_ID, COUNT(fp.Favorite_ProfileId) AS favorites FROM dbo.Favorite_Profiles fp
 GROUP BY fp.Profile_Id
)t3 on t1.Profile_ID = t3.Profile_ID
```

Comment: thanks Andriy M! easy to overlook something when you're writing SQL in a browser. :)  Fixed.